# Sticking HTML 5 table footer at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

Look at the table. It has 3 sections:

- Column headers
- 3 rows with values
- One footer

I am trying to stick the footer at bottom of the page. Table height needs to be resizable, and I need to place a vertical scroll bar if the rows with values exceed the table height limits. I don’t want to expand the row height of the value. Is there a way to do that? (only html/css).

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="table">
        <div class="row headers">
            <div class="cell col1">Col1</div>
            <div class="cell col2">Col2</div>
            <div class="cell col3">Col3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell col1">1</div>
            <div class="cell col2">2</div>
            <div class="cell col3">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell col1">1</div>
            <div class="cell col2">2</div>
            <div class="cell col3">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell col1">1</div>
            <div class="cell col2">2</div>
            <div class="cell col3">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row footers">
            <div class="cell col1">Footer</div>
            <div class="cell col2"></div>
            <div class="cell col3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Styles:

```
.table{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #eee;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
}
.headers { color: #505; font-weight: bold;}
.footers { color: #055;}
.cell{
    background: #eee;
    display:table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.col1 { width:50%;}
.col2 { width:25%;}
.col3 { width:25%;}
```

**Edit:** My table needs to be vertically expandable, and it needs to show a scroll bar when the rows inside header/footer overflows the table height.

Comment: Here's a http://jsfiddle.net/Zpr2r/ for you to put in your question. I'm having trouble understanding your height resizing requirements, can you explain further? Perhaps an example?

Comment: You can use `position: fixed` on the footer.  Semantically, you shouldn't be using `<div>`s.  Have we become so scared of `<table>`s that we won't even use them when they are appropriate?

Comment: Yes, the `<div class="table">` and `.table { display:table }` instead of just `<table>` should really be looked at

Comment: @TreeTree:Okay, let me try to clarify:   My table needs to be vertically expandable, and it needs to show a scroll bar when the rows inside header/footer overflows the table height. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that I made for another post. My table is full expandable, and you can see the scrolls as well.

```
    html, body, #expandtable, #tablecontainer 
    {
        height:100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #tablecontainer 
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
        max-width: 900px;
    }

    #expandtable
    {
        margin: 5px 0 0 0px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 60%;
        border-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #eee;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .breakline { clear:both;}

    .divrow
    {

    }

    .divcell { float:left; border: 1px solid #999; box-sizing: border-box; min-height: 30px; }
    .colname { float:left; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; box-sizing: border-box;}

    .cellwidth1 { width:10%; }
    .cellwidth2 { width:45%; }
    .cellwidth3 { width:35%; }
    .cellwidth4 { width:10%; }

<div id="tablecontainer">

    <div id="topbar">
        <div class="colname cellwidth1">ABC</div>
        <div class="colname cellwidth2">ABC</div>
        <div class="colname cellwidth3">ABC</div>
        <div class="colname cellwidth4">ABC</div>
    </div>
    <div class="breakline"></div>
    <div id="expandtable">
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divrow">
            <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="breakline"></div>
    <div id="topbar">
        <div class="colname cellwidth1">ABC</div>
        <div class="colname cellwidth2">ABC</div>
        <div class="colname cellwidth3">ABC</div>
        <div class="colname cellwidth4">ABC</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gabriel_Mendez/T2pmq/

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all i don't think what you want to do is possible the way you do it. Why do you want to have the footer inside the table?

You have to use positioning to get the footer to the bottom of the page, however:

`The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.`

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

The only solution i could think of is creating a second table for the footer. To make it less complicaded for yourself u suggest to just use the `<table>` elements.

```
<table>
    <theader>
        <tr>
            <th class="col1">Col1</th>
            <th class="col2">Col2</th>
            <th class="col3">Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </theader>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="footer">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            Footer
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
        </td>
        <td class="col3">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now you can just position absolute your footer table:

```
#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

So next problem we're facing is a `<td>` element doesn't react to any overflow. To bypass this you can wrap every content of a `<td>` into a div and set a overflow-y:

```
<td>
     <div>
          12312321312312312312312313123123123123345 long content as example
    </div>
 </td>
```

Now we should also set a static height to the div:

```
td > div, th > div
{
    height: 22px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Also make sure the td content breaks to the y axis:

```
td, th
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #eee;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Now when you wrap every content into a `<div>` it should work, same with the footer table.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABNau/)**

Hope this was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `overflow-y:scroll;` like this:

```
.row{
    display:table-row;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that seems to work for me in Chrome. [**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nw7Y8/) and change the output window height to see the scroll bar appear.

I have used the [CSS3 Flexible Box Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/), the key rule here is `article { -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto; }`. [`flex`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) is a shorthand rule and the first two `1` values for [`flex-grow`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-grow) and [`flex-shrink`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-shrink) allow the `<article>` container to fill up any available space. This, combined with `overflow-y: auto;` causes the scroll bar to appear when then content's height exceeds the available height.

MDN's [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) is also a good summary on these properties.

Now I do think it is a bit wrong to be creating tables without a `<table>` tag, but I couldn't make anything else that worked.

*Note: Sorry it's not a cross-browser demo. I do not have all the latest other browsers installed. If I have time later, I will try to update the CSS.*

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.flex {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%; /* artificial limitation showing scroll on the edge of the "table" */
    overflow: hidden;
}

header, article, footer {
    min-height:24px;
}

header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    color: #505;
    font-weight: bold;
}
article {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
footer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    color: #055;
}
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    max-height:24px;
}
header > div, article > div, footer > div {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
header > :first-child, .row > :first-child, footer > :first-child {
    width:50%;
}
header > :nth-child(2), .row > :nth-child(2), footer > :nth-child(2) {
    width:25%;
}
header > :last-child, .row > :last-child, footer > :last-child {
    width:25%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="flex">
    <header>
        <div>Col1</div>
        <div>Col2</div>
        <div>Col3</div>
    </header>
    <article>
        <div class="row">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <!-- more rows here, removed for brevity -->
    </article>
    <footer>
        <div>Footer</div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need a vertical scroll when table rows get increased and table need to fixed at bottom.

The following solution may work for you.

Wrap your "table" named div tag with the:

```
.tableFooter { height:90px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 90%; /* 90 placed roughly */ }
```